The type initializer for 'Gdip' exception in windows 10
I have a C# app (on .NET 4.8). The operation system is Windows 10.
WriteableBitmap wb =new WriteableBitmap(input.Width,input.Height,96,96, PixelFormats.Bgr24,null);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder;

    switch (bitmapType)
    {
        case BitmapType.TIF:
            encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
            break;

        case BitmapType.JPEG:
            encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            break;

        default:
            encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            break;
    }
    
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wb));
    encoder.Save(ms);
    ms.Flush();

    Bitmap res = new Bitmap(ms);
}

When I run this code with standard user, an exception is raised when bitmap is created. But when I run is as an administrator, the code woks correctly. Why?

Please [edit] your question to include the full complete error message and stack trace.
